# Why this approximation for $\pi$ is so accurate?

Tags: approximation, pi

Berggren and Borwein brothers in "Pi: A Source Book" showed a mysterious approximation for $\pi$ with astonishingly high accuracy:

$$ \left(\frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{n={-\infty}}^\infty e^{-n^2/10^{10}}\right)^2 \approx \pi.$$

In particular, this formula gives $42$ billion (!) correct digits of $\pi$.

I have two questions:

(1) Why this approximation is so much accurate?

(2) Is it possible to prove without computation that this formula is not an identity?

Comment: It reminds me of proof that the integral of the normal distribution is 1.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This isn't actually so mysterious after all; it's just a high precision approximation of the identity
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi},$$
by using very small rectangles to approximate area. By considering these rectangles, you can also see that the areas cannot be equal, since some area will be left over between the rectangles and the graph of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: I can see ${1\over N}\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{-(n/N)^2}$, with $N=10^5$ as a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1e^{-x^2}dx$, but I don't see how the doubly infinite series interprets as a Riemann sum for the integral over $(-\infty,\infty)$. I also don't see how it explains the *extreme* accuracy of the approximation for $\pi$. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you take your sum to range from $n = -aN$ to $aN$, it should be clear that it's a Riemann sum for $\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} \,dx$. Here, we're just limiting $a$ to infinity (which is also how integrals with $\infty$ in their bounds are defined). As for why it's so precise, you can find some bounds on the error of approximation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see now how it's a Riemann sum. But I still don't see how that interpretation explains the *multi-billion*-digit accuarcy; none of the error bounds at the link you provided support any such conclusion.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise it was accurate to billions of *digits*. Under the Riemann sum interpretation it's partially motivated by the fact that underestimations in the concave part cancel with overestimations in the convex part, but I suspect that to prove that they cancel out to *as high* an accuracy as they do one probably wants something more high-powered (like the theta function identity you used).

Comment: I've expanded my own answer to clarify how the theta function identity gives the extreme precision.

Answer (score 22):

It comes from a [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) identity. In particular, if we let

$$\theta(\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{i\pi\tau n^2}$$

for $\tau$ in the upper half plane of complex numbers, then

$$\theta(-1/\tau)=(-i\tau)^{1/2}\theta(\tau)$$

Letting $\tau=i\pi N^2$ with $N=10^5$, we see that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2/N^2}=\theta(-1/(i\pi N^2))=(\pi N^2)^{1/2}\theta(i\pi N^2)=\sqrt\pi N\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi^2N^2n^2}\approx\sqrt\pi N$$

since all terms in the final sum other than $n=0$ contribute extremely small amounts. To be somewhat more precise, we have

$$\begin{align}
{1\over N}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-n^2/N^2}
&=\sqrt\pi\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2N^2n^2}\right)\\
&=\sqrt\pi+2\sqrt\pi\left(e^{-\pi^2N^2}+e^{-4\pi^2N^2}+e^{-9\pi^2N^2}+\cdots \right)\\
&\lt\sqrt\pi+2\sqrt\pi\left(e^{-\pi^2N^2}+e^{-2\pi^2N^2}+e^{-3\pi^2N^2}+\cdots \right)\\
&=\sqrt\pi+{2\sqrt\pi e^{-\pi^2N^2}\over1-e^{-\pi^2N^2}}
\end{align}$$

and for $N=10^5$, we have $e^{-\pi^2N^2}\approx10^{-42{,}863{,}147{,}299.6}$, from which one can see how we get (more than) $42$ billion digits of $\pi$, answering question (1). We also see that the left hand side of the OP's approximation is slightly *smaller* than $\pi$, so the formula is not an identity, answering question (2).

Comment: So, we can claim that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n={-\infty}}^\infty e^{-n^2/N^{2}}\right)^2 = \pi$.

Comment: @JWalter, yes, and it's not necessary for $N$ to be an integer. It might be worth doing a careful error-bound calculation to see if there's some reason the value $N=10^5$ was chosen; I thought I had a copy of the Source Book, but I can't locate it in the chaos of my home library.

Comment: It is interesting as this limit shows the relation between two fundamental constants $e$ and $\pi$.